# NLP: is there any model that generates sentence embedding with self-defined length?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, word-embedding

I found universal sentence encoder https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1

but seems like it can only output sentence vector with 512 dim. I'm new to NLP and like to know whether there exists a model that generates sentence representation with user-defined length.

thanks!

Comment: you would have to train your own if you can not find one where the dimension satisfies your need. What is wrong with 512?

Comment: for my task I want to use sentence embedding as a feature and multiply with the output of bilstm, so the if the dimension doesn't match I can't multiply them.

Comment: why do you not sent the sentence embedding into another feed foward layer with output that is the dimension of the latent dimension of the bilstm.... or better concatenate them :)

Comment: the thing that I don't really understand is during the feature engineering when should I multiply features and when just simply concatenate them...I mean what's the underlying idea of doing so?

Comment: concatenation will nearly be always better than multiplying them as there is a higher capacity to learn. multiplication should be reserved for very particular tasks of deep learning, like attention mechanisms

Comment: well if I select like 5-6 features and combine them in a concatenating manner then my final feature could be really long...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177745/discussion-between-modesitt-and-yingqiang-gao).